# When I use my php post function, It deletes my session cookie without my control

Tags: php, cookies

I set a user cookie when my user logs in to the page and it works correctly. Also, I put a script to all my pages to check cookies. But when I use a php post script, my cookie is being deleted and system automatically send me back to login page. Have you got any idea about that situation?

I have tried to set cookie again in my post.php scripts but it doesn't work.

'

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';


$blok_header = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'blok_header');
$blok_text = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'blok_text');
$Sayfa_Linkleri = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Sayfa_Linkleri');

$sl = $_GET["Sayfa_Linkleri"];
    // Veritabanına Ekleyelim.

$guncelle = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE example_table
  SET blok_header = '$blok_header' , blok_text = '$blok_text', Sayfa_Linkleri = '$Sayfa_Linkleri' ,guncelle = '$now'
  WHERE Sayfa_Linkleri='$sl'") ;


if($guncelle){
      header("location: http://example.com/example-admin/admin/example_edit.php?Sayfa_Linkleri=".$sl);
}
else{
    echo "Bir Sorun Oluştu";
}
?>
```

'

```
<?php
```

if(htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["kullanici"]) == null) 
{

```
header("refresh:1;url=http://www.example.com/example-admin");
```

} 
?>

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using $_COOKIE or $_SESSION to store the data?

Comment: I am using $_COOKIE

Comment: Can you provide the PHP post script that causes trouble?

Comment: Actually, it is my main problem. All my post (insert), upload and update do the same thing.

Comment: Without some code it is really difficult to guess what the problem could be. Just post one of them, it is most likely the same issue for both insert, upload and update

Comment: I put one of my scripts. It's just for a simple update. But it does the same thing too.

Comment: What about the piece of code where the cookie is set, including the piece of code in config.php, where you are checking if the cookie is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem and solve it. If anyone who see the same issue, my problem was about

```
header("location:  http://examplesite/example-admin/admin/some.php");
```

I turned it to

```
header("location: ../../some.php");
```

It worked !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
```

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

```
  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $active = $row['active'];

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  $cookie_name = "kullanici";
  $cookie_value = $myusername;


  if($count == 1) {
     header("location: admin/");
     echo"<div class=\"alert\">
     <span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">&times;</span>
     <strong>Hoşgeldiniz!</strong> Giriş başarılı.
   </div>";
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400), "/");
  }else {
     header("location: index.php");
     echo"<div class=\"alert\">
     <span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">&times;</span>
     <strong>Hata</strong> Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı.
   </div>";
  }
```

}
?>

Comment: This code is where I set my cookies. And I check my cookies in the script which I added to my first question. It is included in config.php